# Prove that if $x$ is a multiple of $a$ and $b$, then $x$ is also a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, least-common-multiple

Prove that if $x$ is a multiple of both $a$ and $b$, then $x$ is also a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.

I couldn’t write a proper conditional logic statement. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's your definition of $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$?

Comment: @Azif00 the least common multiple from the set of multiples of a and b